# Iterating over bytes and printing them to screen as ascii

Tags: assembly, 6502, c64

So I'M attempting to print ASCII to the screen, by storing the ascciASCIIcodes
in a byte array, but it just renders a lot of gunk on the screen.

```
; Message: hello
*=$033C        
        BYTE $48,$45,$49,$49,$4F 
*=$1000
START
    JSR            PRINT_MESSAGE
EXIT
    RTS
PRINT_MESSAGE
    LDX #$00        ; initialize x to 0
    LDA $033C,X     ; grab byte
    JSR $FFD2       ; render text in A with Subroutine:CLRCHN
    INX             ; Incriment X
    CPX #$05        ; We stop at 5
    BNE $1006       ; Else we loop
    RTS
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Further to your own answer, three points you might or might not already know:

1. The C64 uses [PETSCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PETSCII) rather than ASCII - it's similar, but not identical.
2. The memory region $033C-$03FB (192 bytes) is the cassette buffer - it's OK to use that space for temporary storage, but it'll get overwritten when a tape operation occurs.
3. You can speed-up your routine a tiny bit by reversing the order of the bytes to be displayed and counting down in your loop rather than up - which saves you a CMP instruction on each iteration. Note that we use BPL since we want bytes 0-4, and so we wait until X drops below zero before leaving the loop. This restricts the message length to 127 bytes, but then since most of the bottleneck in your code is in the Kernal print routine at $FFD2 this is probably academic. However, the count-down-and-branch technique (instead of count-up-and-compare-and-branch) is a common trick in 6502 coding, since it saves both CPU cycles and bytes.

   ```
   ; Message: hello
   *=$033C        
       BYTE $4F,$49,$49,$45,$48
   *=$1000
   START
       JSR            PRINT_MESSAGE
   EXIT
       RTS
   PRINT_MESSAGE
       LDX #$04        ; initialize x to message length
   GETCHAR
       LDA $033C,X     ; grab byte
       JSR $FFD2       ; render text in A with Subroutine:CLRCHN
       DEX             ; decrement X
       BPL GETCHAR     ; loop until X goes negative
       RTS
   ```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the awesome answer, I'm a complete novice when it comes to assembly (both for the 6502 and in general), it's on my todo list to get a memory map so I know where I can store my code without making the c64 explode :)

And the tip about speed is great to know, my and a co-worker is having a bit of competition about who makes the best 6502 assembly so this will blow his mind thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the mem location I used for my byte array was the course of the problem